# Insert data into first row instead of last row of a worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

Currently I'm using this script to make my data from Outlook emails always replace the data that was in A1.

```
Const xlUp As Long = -4162

Sub ExportToExcel(MyMail As MailItem)
    Dim strID As String, olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strFileName As String

    '~~> Excel Variables
    Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLwb As Object, oXLws As Object
    Dim lRow As Long

    strID = MyMail.EntryID
    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)

    '~~> Establish an EXCEL application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '~~> If not found then create new instance
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Show Excel
    oXLApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Open the relevant file
    Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Control Panel.xlsm")

    '~~> Set the relevant output sheet. Change as applicable
    Set oXLws = oXLwb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    lRow = oXLws.Range("A" & oXLApp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 0

    '~~> Write to outlook
    With oXLws
        '
        '~~> Code here to output data from email to Excel File
        '~~> For example
        '
        .Range("A" & lRow).Value = olMail.Body
        '
    End With

    '~~> Close and Clean up Excel
    oXLwb.save
    Set oXLws = Nothing
    Set oXLwb = Nothing
    Set oXLApp = Nothing

    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

If `Row + 0` makes it overwrite the data,
and `Row + 1` makes it go into the next available cell, how can I make it so that the most recent data will always go into for example, A1 and then make older information move down?

Any tips appreciated. I'm not very savvy when it comes to understanding scripts. I tried `Row - 1` and obviously it did not work.

Comment: I would say you need to post your complete code. The changes you need to do are not in the part you posted yet. [Edit] your question and add the code.

Comment: Hi, edited the code, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert a new row at the top with

```
.Rows(fRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

before you can write into the first row with

```
.Range("A" & fRow).Value = olMail.Body
```

If you have header rows in your table you need to set `fRow` to the first data row:

- E.g. if you have one header row set it `fRow = 2`
- If you don't have any header rows set it `fRow = 1`

---

So we result in something like that:

```
Sub ExportToExcel(MyMail As MailItem)
    Dim strID As String, olNS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strFileName As String

    '~~> Excel Variables
    Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLwb As Object, oXLws As Object
    Dim lRow As Long, fRow As Long

    strID = MyMail.EntryID
    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)

    '~~> Establish an EXCEL application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '~~> If not found then create new instance
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Show Excel
    oXLApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Open the relevant file
    Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Control Panel.xlsm")

    '~~> Set the relevant output sheet. Change as applicable
    Set oXLws = oXLwb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Write to outlook
    With oXLws
        '~~> Code here to output data from email to Excel File
        '~~> For example

        '* insert into last row (old alternative)
        '* you can remove this and the declare of lRow (at the top) if you don't need the old last row insert anymore.
        'lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'next new row
        '.Range("A" & lRow).Value = olMail.Body 'write into last row

        '* insert into first row
        fRow = 1 'first row
        .Rows(fRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank row before first row
        .Range("A" & fRow).Value = olMail.Body 'write into first row
    End With

    '~~> Close and Clean up Excel
    oXLwb.Save
    Set oXLws = Nothing
    Set oXLwb = Nothing
    Set oXLApp = Nothing

    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi :) 
This is great, only i am getting a debug  on  ".Rows(fRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank row before first row"   and i don't know why.

Comment: @Rachael Without detailed error message nobody can help you.

Comment: It just says 'Identifier under cursor is not recognised'.

Comment: @Rachael This is something from the debugger. What's the error message from the message box? And what number did you set for `fRow`?

Comment: Well it seems like its working now, i changed the frow number from 2 to 1 and it's alright. That works great thanks :). Just out of curiosity, i have a workbook with 2 sheets in it. sheet 1 has a formula that picks out a word from the next sheet's a1. but since this macro is creating a new a1, my formula changes its reference to a2. is there anyway i can make sure it always references a1? and the formula beneath it to always reference a2 etc?

Comment: @Rachael Use something like `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1")`. But be use it sparely because `indirect` is a [volatile function](http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/03/03/handle-volatile-functions-like-they-are-dynamite/) and can therefore slow down calculation if used all to frequent.

Comment: Right thank you so much Peh. Been a massive help, deadlines are so stressful :(